# Regex validation fails on 6th character input

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, algorithm, validation

I am doing some url validations and I am getting a failure. It stops all the time after the 6th letter is typed. Below I am typing in "www.google.com" which is in a list of valid urls. However, it fails although it shouldn't.

For example:

```html
w
ww
www
www.
www.g
www.go <-breaks here
www.goo <- continues to break
```

```js
const validUrl = (value: string | null): string => {
    let item: string
    const regex = /^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?((\/)?[a-z0-9-]{1,61}(\/)?){0,30}$/

    if (value === null || value === '') {
      return ''
    }

    if (value && typeof value === 'string' && !regex.test(value)) {
      for (item in urlStrings) {
        if (item.startsWith(value)) {
          return ''
        } else if (value.startsWith(item)) {
          return ''
        }
      }
    }
    return 'Invalid url'
  }
```

This is urlStrings:

```js
export const urlStrings: { [key: string]: string } = {
  'www.costco.com': '',
  'www.walmart.com': '',
  'www.google.com': '',
  'www.facebook.com': '',
}
```

Comment: How about this one ````/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/gm````. BTW: Your ````if```` and the ````else if```` are doing the exact same thing.

Comment: @MustafaYousef it still fails on 6th character with that one, not sure why.

Comment: What's the point of all those `{1}` in your regex? They do nothing. One repetition of X is exactly the same thing as X.

Comment: What is `urlStrings`, and does it play a role in your question? If not, could you reduce the code to just the minimum necessary to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @trincot sorry edited, it's a dicitionary of urls

Comment: Shouldn't you iterate over the keys of `urlStrings`? (Typescript noob here.)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your regex at https://regex101.com/, and it matches `www.go`. However, it doesn't match `www.g` because all groups after the first `\.` require at least two letters (`{2,N}` for some `N`).

Probably, for some reason your code stops working after first failure, and doesn't check further input. However, I was not able to run your code and reproduce the issue.

Hope this helps you.